# How to correctly use ui-btn-left and ui-btn-right class in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, responsive-design, css-float

How to correctly use ui-btn-left and ui-btn-right class

this is what i want
[image]

this is what im getting
[image]

here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/h8JFv/)

my code

```
<div  class="ui-bar ui-bar-b ui-btn-corner-all bar" data-theme="a">
  <div class="ui-btn-left"   >
     <a id="btnlogout" href="javascript:void(0);" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left btnlogout" data-inline="true" data-theme="a">Disconnect</a>
      <a data-role="button" href="javascript:void(0);"  class="imgInfo ui-btn-right" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" style="width:45px;height:45px;" data-theme="a">   </a>
    </div>
 <div class="ui-btn-right" >
       <a  data-role="button" href="javascript:void(0);" class="imgRefresh" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" style="width:45px;height:45px;" onclick="getunreadmessage();" data-theme="a"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe there's a better way. However, here is a quick fix. You can add:

```
.ui-btn-right {
    float: right;
}

.ui-btn-left {
    float: left
}
```

and `<br style="clear: both" />` after your `<div class="ui-btn-right" >` to clear the float

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8JFv/9/)**